# Recover messed up partition and MBR

Tags: partitioning

I did something very stupid.. I wanted to overwrite my MBR of my usb disk and executed the following commands..

```
sudo dd if=./boot0 of=/dev/sdb bs=1b count=1
sudo dd if=./boot1h of=/dev/sdb2
```

Now I can't list the partitions(6 partitions) in sdb. Any suggestions?
I have ubuntu in /dev/sda

```
install-mbr /dev/sdb
```

Dint help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/recover-data-from-a-damaged-hard-disk-using-dd_rhelp.html) helped.. I am still not done yet.. but I atleast see some of my files.. !!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery - testdisk rescued most of the data

Answer (score 1):

I think you can give a try with gparted (if you don't have it go ahead and install it first). The software lets you see your partitions if they are still there. Now what exactly do you want to do?
Is all you want is to make your USB usable again? That would be too easy. Just go to gparted, then delete all the partitions and create new ones.
Or do you want to keep your partitions? Personally I don't think that is possible because you already wiped out your partition table. So what you can try is to back up your remaining data on those partitions (because `dd` didn't delete any data, apart from the little piece at the head of your partitions to make place for the two files). Then format your USB and restore the data.
As far as I know, don't use `dd` unless you are backing up or restoring a whole partition.